# optimization of discrete function on a graph

Tags: optimization, graph-theory, discrete-optimization

I am trying to optimize a complex problem. This is a real world problem that I am trying to summarize in a mathematical format.

**THE PROBLEM**
I need to connect `N` cables from `S_i` start points to `E_i` end points.

A graph `G`  defines where the cables can pass and the maximum number of cables that can pass on each edge.

I need to connect all the cables trying to minimize a certain cost function. This can be for example the number edges used (each edge counts as 1 regardless of how many cables are passing there).

**CURRENT SOLUTION**
I solved the problem using a greedy algorithm by selecting first a cable path between `S_0, E_0` e then the cable between `S_1, E_1` and so on. At each iteration I was taking into account the edges that were still free.

**QUESTION**
Now I think this solution is quiet far from the optimal and I'd like to improve the optimization strategy. Is there any standard approach to solve this type of problems?

**DATA POINTS**
In my current experiment I have 14 start/end tuples  `(S_i,E_i)`. I am able to compute the path from each `S_i`, `E_i` independently from the other and I have around `5000` possible paths each time.

Comment: [Simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) is always worth a punt on these sort of  combinatorial problems with multiple local maxima in a complex space. Rather than try to minimise all the time you allow it to bounce around as if at temperature T and keep track of the very best you have seen. Start out at high T and slowly cool down then warming up if it gets stuck and you can get very good heuristic solutions to really hard problems (at least some of the time).  NO guarantees it is a global maximum but it can work surprisingly well!

Comment: Lookup multi-commodity flow and network-design problems. The latter solved as integer-programming might have good chances to solve your problem to the global optimum if  `I have around 5000 possible paths each time.` is true (which is very small).